# How to fix error that my Vue app doesn't get data from Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I made a Firebase app with database, connected it with Vue app, which is like todo-list. I tried to get a data from database from firebase, which is used to make components for app, but something got wrong. Vue app doesn't get the data from firebase, so items aren't created

It's th error:

> @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.10.0): Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: {"code":"permission-denied","name":"FirebaseError"

Initializing firebase:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";
import { getFirestore } from "@firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "AIzaSyBZlP_E74i40ZLopttFlUbg3j36wirKf9A",
authDomain: "quotes-app-8788c.firebaseapp.com",
projectId: "quotes-app-8788c",
storageBucket: "quotes-app-8788c.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "934346412075",
appId: "1:934346412075:web:5da2928fecb05c834f5a6e"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
 const db = getFirestore(app);


export {
  db
}
```

Here is my code:

```
  onSnapshot(collection(db, 'quotes'), (QuerySnapshot) => {
         const fbquotes = [];
         QuerySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          const quote = {
            id: doc.data().id,
            quoteText: doc.data().quoteText,
            quoteAuthor: doc.data().quoteAuthor,
            quoteGenre: doc.data().quoteGenre,
            timeCreating: doc.data().timeCreating,
            timeEditing: doc.data().timeEditing
          }
          this.fbquotes.push(quote)
         })
         this.quotes = fbquotes
         console.log(this.quotes);
    })
    console.log(this.quotes);
},
```

Comment: Where should I change rules of security using allow read?

Answer (score 0):

The error code "permission-denied" tells that your security rules are not allowing the user to query that whole collection. If a user can read all documents from the "quotes" collection then make sure you have the following rules:

```
match /quotes/{quotesId} {
  allow read: if true; 
}
```

You can change the condition for `allow read` if your requirements are different. Also [Security Rules are not filters](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/what-does-it-mean-that-firestore-security-rules-are-not-filters-68ec14f3d003) so if you want to allow a user to read their own documents only, then make sure you change the query in your code as well to match the security rules.